# How to use arrow keys instead of buttonListeners?

Tags: java, jframe

```
public void setUpButtonListeners() {
        ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Object o = ae.getSource();
                if ((o == slots[3][1]) || (o == slots[3][2])) {
                    slideDown(slots);
                } else if ((o == slots[0][1]) || (o == slots[0][2])) {
                    slideUp(slots);
                } else if ((o == slots[1][3]) || (o == slots[2][3])) {
                    slideRight(slots);
                } else if ((o == slots[1][0]) || (o == slots[2][0])) {
                    slideLeft(slots);
                }
            }
        };
        slots[3][1].addActionListener(buttonListener);
        slots[3][2].addActionListener(buttonListener);
        slots[0][1].addActionListener(buttonListener);
        slots[0][2].addActionListener(buttonListener);
        slots[1][3].addActionListener(buttonListener);
        slots[2][3].addActionListener(buttonListener);
        slots[1][0].addActionListener(buttonListener);
        slots[2][0].addActionListener(buttonListener);
    }
```

This the relevant code. I can find a ton of information on how to add keylisteners to specific JComponents but all I want to do is make it so that if(up arrow pressed) then slideUp(slots), instead of having to press JButtons on the screen to call these functions.

Edit:
Fixed, and it was really simple.
Added

```
frame.setFocusable(true);
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    slideUp(slots);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
```

to constructor.

Comment: there is no point of pressing JButtons, that's not even relevant here. But what do you mean: you want your code to "catch" it when you press up or down even if you don't do it with a specific Component to which you added the listeners selected?

Comment: have you tried adding listener to the Jframe instead of the buttons

Comment: I have coded 2048 and it works. Currently I have it so if you press the top center JButtons, it calls the function slideUp(). I want to be able to press the up arrow key instead of pressing these JButtons to call the function slideUp().

Comment: @KellenCole again: why do you bring up JButtons? they are not relevant to what you are trying to do

Comment: you need to add a keyListener on the JFrame

Comment: You may want to read [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) from the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a custom `KeyEventDispatcher` to handle the arrow key events, otherwise you will have issues with the components focus.

```java
KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
manager.addKeyEventDispatcher( new ArrowsKeyDispatcher() );

...

class ArrowsKeyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
      if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        //Do something here when pressing UP ARROWKEY
      }
      // Do the same for all keys you need to handle globally
      ...
      return false;
    }
  }
```